# Remainder of dividing polynomial of the $n$th degree

Tags: polynomials

> What is the remainder when dividing the polynomial
> $$P(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1$$ with the polynomial
> $$x^3-x$$ if $n$ is a natural odd number?

So, what I know so far is:

$$P(x)=Q(x)D(x)+R(x)$$

In this case I'll call $Q(x) = x^3-x$

$$Q(x) = 0 \iff x=\pm1$$

So from here:

$\begin{array} {l}P(1):\qquad&1^n+1^{n-1}+\cdots+1^1+1=R(1)\\P(-1):&(-1)^n+(-1)^{n-1}+\cdots+(-1)^1+1=R(-1)\end{array}$

Here is where I assumed that $R(x)=ax^2+b$ since $Q(x)=x^3-x$

And from the equations (assuming $n = \{2k+1 \mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}$):

$\begin{array}{l}P(1):\\&R(1)=n\\P(-1):\\&R(-1)=0\end{array}$

And here I get to:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
ax^2+by &=n \\ 
ax^2+by &=0 \\ 
\end{array} 
\right.$$

I would like to know where did I go wrong? Is my assumption for $R(x)$ incorrect, my calculation of the $P(1)$ and $P(-1)$ wrong or is there something else I didn't think about?

Comment: $$Q(x) = 0 \iff x\in\{0,\pm1\}$$

Comment: Oh wow missed that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Experimenting the first few values of $n$: $\:n= 3,5,7,9,11$, you may conjecture the remainder  for the general polynomial $P_n(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+\dots+x^3+x^2+x+1\:$ is
$$R_n(x)=kx^2+(k+1)x+1,\quad\text{ where } k=\left\lfloor \frac n2 \right\rfloor.$$
and try to prove it by induction on $n$ (odd).

You can prove the inductive step (case $n \implies$ case $n+2$) you can try rewriting
$$ P_{n+2}(x)= x^2 P_n(x)+ (x+1)=x^2\bigl[ Q_n(x)(x^3-x)+R_n(x)\bigr]+(x+1), $$
so the remainder for $P_{n+2}$ will be as well the remainder for
$$x^2 R_n(x)+(x+1)=x^2(kx^2+(k+1)x +1)+(x+1)=kx^4+(k+1)x^3+x^2+x+1.$$
You'll only have to prove that the coefficient of $x^2$ thus obtained is $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n+2}2\right\rfloor$ and the coefficient of $x$ is $1$ more.

Answer (score 0):

The remainder is $$\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right)(x^3-x) = \frac{(x+1)(2+(n-1)x)}{2}$$

Comment: The remainder is a polynomial, not a rational fraction.

Comment: @Bernard, this rational function simplifies to the correct polynomial.

Comment: But you don't obtain $\Bigl\lfloor\frac n2\Bigr\rfloor$ as the leading coefficient. Or do I misunderstand your notations?

Comment: @Bernard, I think $[\cdots]$ here are just parentheses.

Comment: @lhf: That's the way I understood them finally, and I had to convince myself it was the same result as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine but you've missed the root $x=0$ of $x^3-x$.

We get $R(0)=P(0)=1$, $R(1)=P(1)=n+1$, $R(-1)=P(-1)=0$.

The quadratic polynomial that interpolates this data is $\frac{n-1}{2} x^2+\frac{n+1}{2}x+1$.

The same approach works when $n$ is even (the interpolation data is different because $P(-1)=1$) and we get $\frac{n}{2} x^2+\frac{n}{2}x+1$.

In both cases, we get the nice recurrence: $R_{n+2}=R_n+x^2+x$, with $R_0=1$ and $R_1=x+1$.